# Creating an Alias for virtualenv ENV in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

How would I go about creating an **alias** for a certain `virtualenv EVN`?

Do I access the `activate_this.py` file in the scripts folder of that `virtualenv` and create a function that calls for a `variable = path/activate, return variable`?

Comment: read this https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up a path to your python scripts folder virtualenv should work as a command

**Path Example:**

`C:\Users\amitrakis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\`

Then just create a windows alias for your specific command:

```
doskey macroEnv=virtualenv EVN
```